# Can't login to Windows XP, error code 0x80004005 

Tags: windows-xp

I'm working on a Windows XP SP3 machine. Everything was working fine but all on a sudden I couldn't login because of this error:

> A problem is preventing Windows from accurately checking the license for this computer. Error Code: 0x80004005

I searched Google and found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306081). I tried it but it's still showing this error.

I don't want to reinstall Windows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What has changed between when it worked and now? Computers don't usually (barring hardware problems) fail for no reason and this is purely a software issue (albeit the OS rather than an application). Did you install some Windows Updates for example?

It could be that the latest version of Windows Genuine Advantage failed to install.

Can you boot to safe mode?

If you can, roll back to a restore point from when you know the machine was working, then perform a manual Windows Update to see what it wants to install. If one of those items is WGA then you could try disabling your anti-virus for the duration of the update.

Comment: I can log into safe mode but unfortunately there are no restore points set. I don't remember what I've installed because I'm restarting it after 1 month.